# How do I prevent my image from disappearing when I use a click event on Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating an image gallery and whenever I click on the image, it displays it fully across the screen. However, whenever I try to click off of it and return to the normal website screen, the image is completely gone.

Here is a codepen showing the problem https://codepen.io/designextras/pen/WNrQMdM

In the html I am targeting the image tag by using firstElementChild in my Javascript for ".services-cell"

```
    <div class="services-cell">
        <img class="services-cell_img" src="gallery/img-1.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="services-cell_text">Digital Marketing</div>
    </div>
```

Here is the Javascript, it is also in the codepen above

```
 let galleryImages = document.querySelectorAll('.services-cell');
 let getLatestOpenedImg;
 let windowWidth = window.innerWidth;


 if(galleryImages) {
  galleryImages.forEach(function(image, index){
    image.onclick = function() {
        console.log(image.firstElementChild);

        getLatestOpenedImg = index + 1;

        let container = document.body;
        let newImgWindow = document.createElement('div');
        container.appendChild(newImgWindow);    
        newImgWindow.setAttribute('class', 'img-window');
        newImgWindow.setAttribute('onclick', 'closeImg()');

        let newImg = image.firstElementChild;
        newImgWindow.appendChild(newImg);
        newImg.classList.remove('services-cell_img');
        newImg.classList.add('popup-img');


    }
 })
 }

 function closeImg() {
 document.querySelector('.img-window').remove();
 }
```

and here is the CSS classes that I'm trying to add whenever I click on the image

```
        .img-window {
            width: 100vw;
            height:100vh;
            background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 100;
            cursor: pointer;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }


        .popup-img {
            max-height: 80vh;
            max-width: 80vw;
            z-index: 200; 
        }
```

So the bottom function closeImg() seems to be the problem, but I don't know else I'd write my code in order to close out the image pop up and return to the screen without it completely removing my image from the html

Comment: Create a css class that does what you want.

Comment: my entire image html tag is what is disappearing so how I add a CSS class to solve the img tag from not disappearing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you append the image to `newImgWIndow`, you're removing it from its original DIV. You should clone the image instead of moving it.

```
        let newImg = image.firstElementChild.cloneNode();
        newImgWindow.appendChild(newImg);
        newImg.classList.remove('services-cell_img');
        newImg.classList.add('popup-img');
```